# incompatible pointer types sending UIFont to parameter of type NSDictonary?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, sigabrt, uifont

I got incompatible pointer types sending UIFont to parameter of type NSDictonary and it is making me get a signal SIGABRT and i don't know what it means here is my code that im getting the error in...

```
- (void)drawDayNumber {
    if (self.selectionState == DSLCalendarDayViewNotSelected) {
    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:66.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] set];
    }
    else {
        [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    }

    UIFont *textFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    CGSize textSize = [_labelText sizeWithAttributes:textFont];//Im getting it here.

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(ceilf(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - (textSize.width /2.0)), ceilf(CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) - (textSize.height / 2.0)), textSize.width, textSize.height);
    [_labelText drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:textFont];//And here.
}
```

Comment: Look at the docs for the `NSString sizeWithAttributes:` method. Then look at what you are passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Crash 1

Issue is with this code:

```
[_labelText drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:textFont];
```

2nd parameter of `drawInRect:withAttributes:` method expects `NSDictionary`, you are passing `UIFont` object. That is the reason for the crash.

You should do something like:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: textFont,NSFontAttributeName,nil];
[_labelText drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:dict];
```

**or**

You can use: `drawInRect:withFont` method instead.

```
[_labelText drawInRect:rect withFont:textFont];
```

---

#### Crash 2

In the following code:

```
CGSize textSize = [_labelText sizeWithAttributes:textFont];
```

here also the parameter is wrong, `sizeWithAttributes:` method expects `NSDictionary`, you are passing `UIFont` object.

Change that to:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: textFont,NSFontAttributeName,nil];
CGSize textSize = [_labelText sizeWithAttributes:dict];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a dictionary for the attributes:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : textFont};
```

You should use this `attributes` dictionary as the parameter for these methods. If you want to set the font color, too, you might do the following:

```
UIColor *color;
if (self.selectionState == DSLCalendarDayViewNotSelected)
    color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:66.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
else
    color = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIFont *textFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName            : textFont,
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color};

CGSize textSize = [_labelText sizeWithAttributes:attributes];

CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(ceilf(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - (textSize.width /2.0)), ceilf(CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) - (textSize.height / 2.0)), textSize.width, textSize.height);
[_labelText drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:attributes];
```

See the [NSAttributedString Application Kit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000167-BAJJCCFC) for a list of the various keys you can use in this `NSDictionary` for the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a `UIFont` object to a method that requires a Dictionary. You need to create a dictionary with which ever keys you wish to set.

You where probably thinking of this method.

```
[_labelText sizeWithFont:font];
```

Comment: oh ok thanks, im pretty new. and i bet this is pretty basic but how do i create a dictionary

Comment: Edited my answer to include a method that will help you out, and will work with the UIFont rather than having to create a dictionary.

Comment: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary.html Take a look at that and it will give you a start on NSDictioanry and then you would need to google what keys you need to set for attributed text.